# Outputed lines doesn't wrap correctlly within a terminal in Non Canonical mode

Tags: c, bash, shell, terminal, termcap

I am trying to implement a mini version of bash using `Termcap` capabilities, and now I am trying to read user's input and retype it in the terminal Stdout.

Every thing is working fine, but the problem occurs when trying to resize the terminal window, as you can see in the below gif, when I write a **SINGLE** line and then shrink the window, and expand it again the output wraps good as it should.

[image]

But when my text goes past the first terminal line (without pressing Enter), if I do the same steps as before, the output wrapping is different from what I want. What I need is that the last characters of the first line must join with the second line characters when shrinking the window, and vice versa when I expand the window the first characters of the second line join with the first line characters.

[image]

***Is there a way to make the outputted lines wrap exactly the same as bash ?*** (joining lines with each other)

Here is my code so far, use `-ltermcap` flag when you want to compile it and Thanks in advance.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <termcap.h>
#include <termios.h>
# include <sys/ioctl.h>
# include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int     g_screen_width = 0;
int     g_cursor_colm = 0;
int     g_printed = 0;

int     ft_putchar(int c)
{
    int len = write(1, &c, 1);
    return (len);
}

int     ft_isprint(int c)
{
    return (c >= 32 && c < 127);
}

void    update_cursor_position()
{
    g_cursor_colm = g_printed % g_screen_width;
}

void    update_screen_width()
{
    struct winsize w;
    
    ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
    g_screen_width = w.ws_col;
}

void    sigwinch_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGWINCH)
    {
        update_screen_width();
        update_cursor_position();
    }
}

void    move_cursor_to_colum(int col)
{
    char    *ch_cap;
    
    ch_cap = tgetstr("ch", NULL);
    tputs(tgoto(ch_cap, 0, col), 1, ft_putchar);
}

void    move_cursor_down_vertically()
{
    char    *do_cap;

    do_cap = tgetstr("do", NULL);
    tputs(do_cap, 1, ft_putchar);
}

void    move_cursor_to_next_line()
{
    move_cursor_to_colum(0);
    move_cursor_down_vertically();
}

void    enable_raw_mode()
{
    struct termios raw;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &raw);
    raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}

void    disable_raw_mode(struct termios old_termios_state)
{
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &old_termios_state);
}

int main()
{
    struct termios  original_termios_state;
    char            *term_type = getenv("TERM");
    char            c;
    char            *line;

    tgetent(NULL, term_type);
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &original_termios_state);
    enable_raw_mode();

    update_screen_width();
    signal(SIGWINCH, sigwinch_handler);
    while (read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1))
    {
        if (ft_isprint(c))
        {
            ft_putchar(c);
            g_printed++;
            g_cursor_colm++;
            if (g_cursor_colm == g_screen_width)
            {
                g_cursor_colm = 0;
                move_cursor_to_next_line();
            }
        }
        else if (c == 27) // ESC
        {
            disable_raw_mode(original_termios_state);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    disable_raw_mode(original_termios_state);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `from what it should be` how should it be? For me, it should be as it is. If you want your custom semantics, you would go with ncurses and you would redraw the whole screen on resize.

Comment: @KamilCuk there are two lines in the second gif, when I shrink the window, the last character from the first line shall join the second line, but instead the last character goes to the second line, and the 'old' second line goes to the third line, and this is not what it shall do.

Comment: `shall join` no it shouldn't, it should behave as shown. Do you have any reference that it "should"? Ie. what is that assumption based on that it should behave in that way?  You can view your output in `vim` or `less` ie. use `ncurses` and redraw output on resize. Anyway, this has _nothing_ to do with your program. The terminal - the program you are resizing - makes the decision to wrap the lines.

Comment: @KamilCuk well when you open your terminal and write some lines and try to shrink the window the lines get joined together, I need to do the same behavior.

Comment: Did you output a newline character at the end of the first line?  If so, the behaviour you see is what I would expect.

Comment: @PaulSanders I have tried that, with the same behavior, yeah I got you this the normal behavior, but is there any way to join the first line with the second line, or shall I retype those lines on resizing?

Comment: I actually don't know, I was just throwing a suggestion in.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yeah, you are right I tried vim and it is as you said, but how shall i retype those lines? If the cursor were in the second line and I shrink  the window as you can see in the second gif, normally I need to move the cursor up one line (in order to clear and retype), but with the terminal auto wrap I need to move it up 2 times, and I guess it will be more complicated with a lot of lines.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Judging by your second animated screenshot, it seems obvious to me that "tempor" is followed by a newline. Else, when the terminal size is the widest, it would be followed by the first characters of "incididunt". BTW, you did not say what terminal this is. Did you try with other terminal applications?

Comment: @xhienne it is gnome-terminal in ubuntu, I have tried  tilda terminal, with the same behavior.

Comment: @Holysemicolon Can you try mate-terminal? This is what I'm using and I think it might handle this properly. Why do I think so? Because when I select a loooog line of text that spans multiple lines of my terminal, and then copy-paste it in vim, there is no additional newline added where the lines ended on my terminal, contrary to other terminal apps I have used in the past. So, clearly, my terminal remembers where there are actual newlines, and where the lines wrapped due to the terminal width.

Comment: @xhienne unfortunately, the same behavior, I think this is the normal behavior in most of terminals as the others stated above, I liked the mate-terminal though

Comment: @Holy One thing is still not clear to me (this is also Paul Sanders' question): is there a newline character after "tempor" or not (i.e. did you press enter at the end of the first line)?

Comment: @xhienne no there isn't, when the cursor reach the screen width, I move the cursor down, then I move it to column 0, and write the new output on that line.

Comment: have you tried not moving the cursor at all (i.e. don't call `move_cursor_to_next_line();`) and let the terminal do it when the cursor reaches the right margin?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I have just tried it, and it works perfectly, but the problem is that I need to move the cursor in order to insert new characters in the middle of un outputted line, for example when you click on left arrow, the cursor will move to the left and so on.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_node/termcap_32.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your terminal remembers where there are actual line skips (the one that you do explicitly with cursor_down in `move_cursor_down_vertically()`), as opposed to line wraps the terminal does on its own due to its limited width.

So:

- either you don't move (downwards) your cursor at all and do all your processing on only *one* virtual line of text, letting the terminal wrap that line according to its width (this is probably the easiest solution);
- or you redraw the screen yourself in `sigwinch_handler()` when you receive the SIGWINCH signal.

Comment: I 'll need to move the cursor around in order to traverse the outputted line and insert or delete a character, so the first option is not suitable for me.
I tried to remove `move_cursor_down_vertically()` and it worked perfectly for me in `mate-terminal`, when the cursor reach the end of the line it goes to the second line, but when I try it in `genom-terminal` when the cursor reach the end of the line it doesn't go down, and when I write new character the last character on the first line get replaced with the new character, and so on.
so it depends on which terminal I am using.

Comment: the second option is the best as far as I know, but there is a problem, for example there are two lines, the cursor in the second line, when I shrink the terminal the last character from the first line goes to the second line and the old second line goes to the third line, so now the cursor is on the third line,  in order to retype the output I'll need to move the cursor up 2 times and then clear and retype the output.
but how can I know  how much shall I move the cursor up?

Comment: because the cursor were in the second line but when I shrinked the window the cursor moved to the third line, and it will be too complicated with a lot of lines.
for an example in this image the cursor is in the third line https://imgur.com/VIvrPw9 but when I'll shrink the window the cursor will be in the 5th line as in https://imgur.com/vUgMDVW

Comment: @Holysemicolon The cursor position is not a problem. As I understand your question, you want all your lines to be glued together, therefore its easier to think in 1D and consider your text as one big line: on SIGWINCH you can calculate the new 2D cursor position as (1D-pos % term-width, 1D-pos / term-width). This reasoning works for both solutions. The advantage of solution #1 is you don't have to redraw everything; your only problem seems to be gnome-term not doing line wrapping: did you try `tput smam` (or the programming equivalent)?

Comment: it is my bad, it turned out that I was calling this function `ft_putstr(tgetstr("RA", NULL));` with `RA` the termcap capability for turning off automatic margins, so that's why I had that behavior in Genome-term.
I have fixed the problem now thanks to you, now I don't move the cursor down to the next line with `termcap` capabilities as in `move_cursor_down_vertically()` , rather than that when the cursor reach the right margin I write space in order to let the cursor move down then I move the cursor left and clear the line the cursor is on, then output the new characters.

Comment: I did it this is way in order to insert new characters in the middle of an outputted line, since I have an other code that I am working in, which I can move left and write with arrows and insert or delete characters within an outputted line.

Comment: @Holysemicolon Glad it works now. Happy programming!